# How can I pass the currently defined variables into an included file by a function

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a file using a function, and I have several variables defined. I want to access the included file to access the variables, but because I am including it using a function, it is not accessible. The sample scenerio is as follows:

i.e the contents of index is as follows

`index.php`

```
<?
...
function include_a_file($num)
{
  if($num == 34)
    include "test.php";
  else
    include "another.php"
}
...
$greeting = "Hello";
include_a_file(3);
...
?>
```

And the contents of test.php is as follows

`test.php`

```
<?
echo $greeting;
?>
```

The test file is throwing a warning saying the `$greeting` is not defined.

Comment: define `$greeting` as a constant instead

Comment: sorry that was a sample scenerio, i have more than 10 variables defined. Also, they changes.

Comment: @jayharris What would defining it as a constant to more than just setting `$greeting ="";` ?

Comment: @DarylGill makes it global, and in the include file you can read the constant to a variable after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. `include` and `require` act as if the code you're including was literally part of the file at the point the include/require was executed. As such, your external files are going to be in the scope of the `include_a_file()` function, which means `$greeting` is OUT OF SCOPE within that function.

You'll have to either pass it in as a parameter, or make it global within the function:

```
function include_a_file($num, $var) {
                              ^^^^-option #1
   global $greeting; // option #2
}

$greeting = 'hello';
include_a_file(3, $greeting);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your correctly including? And remember PHP is case sensitive:

```
$Test = "String"; 
$TEst = "String";
```

Both completely different variables..

Furthermore, don't just echo out a variable, wrap it within in a `isset` condition:

```
if (isset($greeting)){
 echo $greeting;
} // Will only echo if the variable has been properly set..
```

Or you could use:

```
if (isset($greeting)){
  echo $greeting;
}else{
  echo "Default Greeting"; 
}
```